# Silent logout in MSAL angular

Tags: javascript, angular, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I have impletemted the MSAL angular in one of my project. I have a feature to log out. Once the user has clicked on logout it should not redirect or popup to select the account and sign out. Is there any way make a fix.

Comment: Is the issue that it requires the user to select the account or that it redirects? In theory the tokens the front-end has could be cleared, but then the user would not truly be signed out. The redirect to AAD is necessary to properly sign the user out.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by @ [***amanpreetsingh-msft***](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/users/50136/amanpreetsingh-msft.html) ,To achieve the above requirement we can use the [**`V1 endpoint for sign-out user requests`**](https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/logout), which will skip the prompt to select the user account.

For more details please Refer this:- [***MS Q&A | Bypass the the account selection screen while logout***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/759538/bypass-the-the-account-selection-screen-while-logo.html) & [***GitHub|Sample***](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/logout.md).